# Confusion with /e/ sound

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

An exercise from English pronunciation in use (Elementary), J. Marks:

Seven of these numbers have /e/. Which are they?

Three, seven, eight, ten, eleven, twelve, thirteen, seventeen, eighteen, twenty, seventy, eighty, a hundred.

The correct answer: seven, ten, eleven, twelve, seventeen, twenty, seventy.

**But what about: eight /eɪt/, eighteen /ˌeɪ'tiːn/ and eighty /'eɪti/?**

Comment: /e/ (written thus) is a phoneme. It is a different phoneme from the diphthong /eɪ/. It would be possible to have an analysis of English where /eɪ/ was treated as a sequence of two phonemes, but that is certainly not common.

Comment: 1. *Eight* is transcribed phonemically `/eɪt/`, not `/eit/` (phonetically `[eɪ̯t]`, not `[eit]`). 2. Diphthong `/eɪ/` is different from `/e/` and `/ɪ/` together, which can be denoted more explicitly phonetically by writing it as `[eɪ̯]` (as I did) or with the `ɪ` in the superscript (like the `2` in `²`). For `[eɪ̯eɪ]` you'd know there's a diphthong there (`[eɪ̯]`), together with two other vowels: `[e]` and `[ɪ]`. 3. Nobody bothers with this in phonemic transcriptions in English as it probably doesn't occur. 4. If we trust CMUdict, there are no words (pronunciations) matching `EH\d? IH\d?`.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, the /e/ is a different phoneme from the **diphthong** /eɪ/.

A vowel can either be a *monopthong* or a *diphthong*. A monopthong is a vowel sound in which the speech organs remain in the same position throughout the production of the vowel sound (i.e. the vowel quality doesn't change). The /e/ in words like *met, set, let* etc., is a monopthong

A diphthong, on the other hand, involves a change in the position of the speech organs (i.e. the vowel quality changes). For example, the vowel in *mate, sate, late* is a diphthong /eɪ/.

In the OP, *eight, eighty, eighteen* have the diphthong /eɪ/ not the monopthong /e/, so they're excluded from the words having /e/.